# MVC - View without model but has one field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a page which will require a password field only. User has to enter his password then submit. Is it possible to create a view for that without a model? I asked because if I need to create a model then it will have a password property only. I hope there is a simple way for this simple page.

Comment: You can use `ViewBag` or `ViewData["Password"]`.

Comment: Create a view model, otherwise you will not have strong typed binding and you will loose the benefits of client and server side validation

Comment: you can create a normal html page as view if you want and access the values using the formscollection in the action,you can get all the forms values

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create View Model then it is completely fine. You can loose some benefit like automatic client side validation ( data annotation). It means you have to do all validation by your self in client side and later on server side.

This is simple way you can do that.

Your controller code something look like this.

```
public ActionResult AcceptPasswordOnly(string Password)
        {
            // Do your validation if want password back to field if validation failed then set in  ViewData["Password"] = Password                 
            return View();
        }
```

Your view code something look like this.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("AcceptPasswordOnly", "Home"))
    {
        <div>Enter Passowrd :</div> @Html.TextBox("Password" , ViewData["Password"] ?? "")
        <input type="submit" />
    }
```

Note: Just remember that @Html.TextBox first argument is name and controller method parameter must same so you can access directly.

This way you can do directly without creating model and just using primitive datatype.